# Why does the --include switch in grep behave differently when both machines are on 11.10?

Tags: command-line, compatibility, grep

I have used the same following commands (in `xterm`) on two machines of the same ubuntu (11.11-64bit).

```
grep "jars2deploy" --include=*.xml ./* -r
```

However, one machine `A`  only search for xml file, as expected, while the other `B` totally ignored `--include` switch. I have tried `grep --version`, which shows `grep` are of the same version `2.9` as well. My question is how I can config on machine `B` so the same command searches .xml file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isn't the GLOB incomplete?

```
grep "jars2deploy" --include=*.xml ./ -r
```